# How to solve asymptotic recurrence without using Master Theorem

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I am working on the following problem.

Consider the function $B:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by:
$$B(n) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $n\leq 2$,}\\
3\cdot B(\lceil n/\log_2 n\rceil) + n & \text{if $n\geq 3.$}
\end{cases}
$$

Find an explicit function $g(n)$ such that $B(n) \in \Theta(g(n)).$

I can see that $n\in O(B(n))$, and intuitively it seems as though $B(n)\in O(n)$, too.
However, I am not sure how to rigorously show this.  Furthermore, the Master Theorem cannot be directly applied in this case.

I would appreciate suggestions as to how to solve this problem.